# Prove that 1$^{−1}$ = 1 using only field axioms.

Tags: field-theory

The question that I am currently stuck on is

> Let $F$ be a field. Prove that $1^{−1} = 1$ using only field axioms.

So far, I have gone over the 6 major field axioms and have tired using the identify $a * 1 = a$.

Comment: What is your definition of $x^{-1}$?

Comment: Have you shown inverses are unique, or else are you able to assume they are unique? If so, can you tell us how exactly you tried to use the identity $a\cdot 1=a$?

Comment: @HenrySwanson That is pretty standard

Comment: @6005 Yeah, but once they type it out explicitly, they can probably get it on their own...

Comment: $$1^{-1} 
\underset{
\begin{array}{c}
\uparrow\\
1 \verb/ is multiplicative/\\
\verb/identity /\end{array}
}{=}
1^{-1} \cdot 1 
\underset{
\begin{array}{c}
\uparrow\\
1^{-1} \verb/ is multiplicative/\\
\verb/ inverse of /1
\end{array}
}{=}
1$$

Comment: @archille hui I have dont that before but wasnt really sure if that is correct.

Comment: @Zero aside from using the field axioms twice (one for the existence of $1$ and the other one for the existence of $1^{-1}$), this is everything you need.

Comment: ok thank you that makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

$1 \cdot 1 = 1$ and so $u \cdot 1 = 1 = 1 \cdot u$ with $u=1$.

This proves that $u=1$ is the multiplicative inverse of $1$, by uniqueness of the multiplicative inverse.

Comment: @achille hui gave a much better proof in the comments.